# how to override yeoman generators?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to find a way how can I edit the default generators of generator-angular. In rails I can edit or create new generators here I am trying to create a scaffold like generator .

I want to edit this.

```
 yo angular:controller user
```

it is generating :

```
app/scripts/controllers/user.js:
angular.module('myMod').controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope) {
```

// ...
});

Is there any way I can create my own sub command like :

```
 yo angular:scaffold user
```

which should generate views + route + controller I like yoman but I am unable to find this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the routes generator to create scaffold it is not a pure scaffold but for that you can edit the generators first you can use this command :

```
yo angular:route myroute
```

This will generate :

```
app/scripts/controllers/myroute.js

 angular.module('myMod').controller('MyrouteCtrl', function ($scope) {
 // ...
});

app/views/myroute.html
```

If you want to customize the view file you can go to node_modules global file yo can find it here :

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular
```

And you will see a list of files you can see it here :https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

here you need to change the file called :

```
/templates/common/app/views/view.html
```

here you can add you custom materials for you site and if you want to edit the controller for that you need to go to :

```
generator-angular/route/index.js
```

here you can edit how your generator behave , you can see this for more info how to edit or create yeoman generator.